# Having trouble setting up a web scraper with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Three days ago I started learning Python to create a web scraper and collect information about new book releases. I´m stuck on one of my target websites...I know this is a really basic question but I´ve watched some videos, looked at many related questions on stack overflow, tried more than 10 different solutions and nothing. If anybody could help, much appreciated:

**My problem:**
I can retrieve the title information but can´t retrieve the price information

**Data Source:**
https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/non-fiction/business-and-management/?pagesize=25

**My code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/non-fiction/business-and-management/?pagesize=25'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
```

*#code to retrieve title*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for productdetails in soup.find_all("div", class_='figDetails'):
    producttitle = productdetails.a.text
    print(producttitle)
```

*#code to retrieve price*

```
for productpricedetails in soup.find_all("div", class_='related-products-block'):
    productprice = productdetails.find("div", class_="new-price").span.text
    print(productprice)
```

There are two elements with the name span, I need the information on the second one but don´t know how to get to it.
Also, on trying different possible solutions I kept getting a noneType error...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the source you're trying to scrape populates this data via Javascript.

Viewing the source of the page you can see the raw HTML shows the div you're trying to target is empty.

```html
<html>   
... 
    <div class="related-products-block" id="reletedProduct_490420">
    </div>
...
</html>
```

You can also see this if you update your second loop like so:

```py
for productpricedetails in soup.find_all("div", class_="related-products-block"):
    print(productpricedetails)
```

**Edit**:

As a bonus, you can inspect the Javascript the page uses. It is very easy to understand, and the request simply returns the HTML which you are looking for. It will be a bit more involved to get the JSON prepared for the requests but here's an example:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/catalog/RelatedProductsData"

payload = {"productId": 490420, "type": "List", "ordertype": 0, "formatType": 0}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode("utf8"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I know it´s probably clear but I still don´t get what I´m supposed to do...

Comment: I get what you said about the div being empty. My mistake was that I was inspecting in the web browser to check the div, lesson learned. I still don´t get which parts of my code I´m supposed to change though.